# Exam document class and Hieroglyphs

Tags: exam

Good day to everyone.
I am using the exam document class to type my questions paper, and in the preamble I add the Hieroglf pakage. But unfortunately when compiling \Hten, \Hhundred ...it shows but 2,3...,instead of egyptian numerals

Comment: please always show in a code block a complete small document that shows the problem

Answer (score 1):

As described in the hieroglf [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/archaic/hieroglf/hieroglf.pdf) (page 3), you need to select the hieroglyph font before using commands like `\Hten`. This can be done with a font switch `\pmhgfamily`, which uses the hieroglyph font for all following text until a different font switch is used, or with the command `\textpmhg{}` for which only the argument is rendered in the font (similar to for example `\textbf{}`).

This font selection is needed in all classes, not just for `exam`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\begin{document}
These are hieroglyph numbers: \textpmhg{\Hten \Hhundred}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it now works